# How to detect newline in an input

Tags: java

I am given this exercise, but I am having trouble finding a way to catch the new line. Can you please help me?

Write a program that reads user input until an empty line. For each non-empty string, the program splits the string by spaces and then prints the pieces that contain av, each on a new line.
Here is mycode:

```
public class AVClub {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList();
        String line;
        while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("")){
            str.add(line);     
        }
        for(int i=0; i<str.size();i++){
            if(str.get(i).contains("av")){
                System.out.println(str.get(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your program seems to correctly identify an empty line. Are you finding that this is not the case?

Comment: you do that already with scanner.nextLine()
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: There is nothing in the quoted assignment about 'catch the new line'. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following requirement has been wrongly implemented in your code:

> For each non-empty string, the program splits the string by spaces and
>   then prints the pieces that contain av, each on a new line.

It should be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList();
        String line;
        System.out.print("Enter sentences (blank line to terminate): ");
        while (!(line = scanner.nextLine()).equals("")) {
            str.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Words containig 'av' are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
            line = str.get(i);
            String[] words = line.split("\\s+"); // Split the string on spaces
            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.contains("av")) {
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** you have to check each word in every sentence whether the word contains `av`. Your code checks for `av` in each sentence.

**A sample run:**

```
Enter sentences (blank line to terminate): harry is a good boy
my name is avinash
Is there any seats available in the aviation training
hello world

Words containig 'av' are: 
avinash
available
aviation
```

**Note:** If you need to check `av` in a case insensitive way, do it as `if (word.toUpperCase().contains("AV"))`.